# Does mechanical energy remain constant during an inelastic collision?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, momentum, collision

Suppose two bodies collide inelastically, does the total loss in kinetic energy get converted into potential energy associated with the deformation? Or does the energy also transform into other forms like sound or light?

Answer (score 1):

Well, look at it this way: if you shoot two billard balls at each other and your hear a loud CRACK!, the energy of the sound wave has to have to come from *somewhere*. In other words, some of the two balls' initial energy *must* have been converted to sound.

In general, I believe there is no reason for the mechanical energy to be conserved: the total loss in kinetic energy during an inelastic collision may go to creating light, sound, heating the object (thermal energy), deforming it (elastic energy) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

> does the total loss in kinetic energy get converted into potential
> energy associated with the deformation?

It depends on what type of deformation you are talking about and what you mean by "loss of kinetic energy".

There are two broad categories of deformation: Elastic (temporary) and Inelastic or plastic (permanent). They are associated with elastic and inelastic collisions, respectively.

In a perfectly elastic collision, some kinetic energy may be converted to elastic potential energy (with the remainder retained as kinetic energy of the colliding objects after the collision). In a perfectly elastic collision any deformation is temporary and totally recoverable. An example is a perfectly elastic collision of an object with an ideal spring. In a perfectly elastic collision total mechanical energy is conserved. Therefore no kinetic energy is "lost" in the sense that total mechanical energy is conserved.

However in the macroscopic world there are no perfectly elastic collisions. Some part of the energy is always dissipated, ie., converted to internal energy of atoms and molecules.

On the other hand, kinetic energy lost in an inelastic collision is energy lost due to  inelastic or plastic (permanent) deformation of the colliding objects. The loss is primarily in the form of heat with generally much less in the form of sound. Such permanent deformation is not elastic potential energy, since the deformation is permanent and non recoverable.  The kinetic energy is lost in the sense that total mechanical energy (kinetic + potential) is not conserved.

Hope this helps.